# Show a UIView when a variable meets a condition

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uilabel, swift3

I have a model object called `PlayerStore` which is an array of `Player` objects. These get added to the `MainVC` view controller's `UITableView`. Here a user can add `Player` objects that are displayed in `UITableView`.

I have a `UILabel` that is an `@IBOutlet` called `pressPlusLbl` that I want to only display when there are no players left in the `PlayerStore`.

I can handle that easily when the view loads in `ViewDidLoad` with something like:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        players = store.getAllPlayers()
        emptyTableShowsLabel()

    }

    func emptyTableShowsLabel(){

        if !store.hasPlayers(){
            pressPlusLbl.isHidden = false
            // TODO: maybe animate this view?
            // TODO: hide the table
        } else {
            pressPlusLbl.isHidden = true
            // TODO: bring back the table
        }
    }
```

But I always want my view controller to listen to the model objects (PlayerStore) to know when it's empty: `!store.hasPlayers()` so that I can display the `pressPlusLbl` again.

**EDIT 1:**

Don't know if it's relevant, but here's one of the places the user can delete from the TableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete){

        store.deletePlayer(row: indexPath.row)
        players = store.getAllPlayers()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)

    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** 
Looking to implement a delegate pattern from the `PlayerStore`. Here's what I have that builds but doesn't quite work.

in `MainVC.Swift` (View Controller) using my existing protocols:

```
protocol PlayerIncrementor {
    func increment(playerPosition: Int)
    func decrement(playerPosition: Int)
    func isStoreEmpty()
}

class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, PlayerIncrementor {

...

    func isStoreEmpty() {

        store.delegate = self

        if store.hasPlayers() {
            pressPlusLbl.isHidden = true
        } else {
            pressPlusLbl.isHidden = false
        }

    }

}
```

In the `PlayerStore.swift` (Model)

```
class PlayerStore {

...

    var delegate: PlayerIncrementor!

    private var _playerArray = [Player]()

    func hasPlayers() -> Bool {
        return !_playerArray.isEmpty
    }


...

}
```

Comment: How do the `tableView` gets notified that user deleted the `player`

Comment: @New16 added the code.

Comment: @Macness Please check my answer and reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Delegate pattern.

```
protocol MainViewControllerDelegate {
    func playersDidChange()
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController, MainViewControllerDelegate {

    func playersDidChange() {
        // Check store to determine if label is to be shown
    }
}
```

Then in your player store simply create a reference to the delegate and call delegate.playersDidChange function.

When you add/remove a player from your player store, you can call the delegate. For example,

```
class PlayerStore {

    func addPlayer(player: Player) {
        // Add player to your array
        delegate.playersDidChange()
    }

    func removePlayer(player: Player) {
        // Remove player from your array
        delegate.playersDidChange()
    }
}
```

So in your UITableViewDelegate function,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

By calling store.removePlayer function, your label isHidden will be handled by the MainViewControllerDelegate.

Also, you just have to set store.delegate = self once, probably right after you initialised the store.

Comment: Your solution is elegant and I'm not sure I'm doing it right. I updated my code under "Edit 2" in an attempt. It's not working at the moment.

Comment: updated it and refactored for a single use. This is much better than copying a running bool every time i add or remove from the model.

Answer (score 0):

Call checkTableData() after deleting the row:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete){

        store.deletePlayer(row: indexPath.row)
        players = store.getAllPlayers()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.bottom)
checkTableData()

    }
}

 func checkTableData() {

              if !store.hasPlayers(){
                        pressPlusLbl.isHidden = false
                        // TODO: maybe animate this view?
                        // TODO: hide the table
                    } else {
                        pressPlusLbl.isHidden = true
                        // TODO: bring back the table
                    }


            }
```

Don't forget to reload the tableView.

Comment: I don't want the ViewController to check periodically. I want it to know there are no more players by listening to the model.

Comment: the problem with this is that I have to check every method that inserts/deletes rows. I don't want to add this to each method - I think I'm looking for a delegate here from the PlayerStore.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check this is where you basically editing the datasource. So, in your case `numberOfRowsForSection`, `commitEditingStyle`. If you try to insert also, you may need to remove the label if the datasource count goes higher.